The size of the image is too big for the button... Any tips?
BEFORE AFTER! the light gray is the button. I have this css for my html button:
.link-container button {
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(imgs/openbutton.png);
}


this is the html code for the button:
        <button onclick="window.location.href='https://example.com/link2';"></button>
the main problem is, its too big.
I have searched online for solutions, havent found anything, and I was kind expecting for it to shrink and fit...

Set the size using background-size?

@Cyclonecode Yes, I tried using Utsav katharotiya answer. Didnt work.
